# Ubuntu 18.04 2 display adapters -monitors. No output on 2nd screen no configuration option

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics

fairly new to linux so excuse me if I miss something obvious.
Im trying to use 2 monitors each attached to a different VGA adapter on an Ubuntu 18.04 box.
The first adapter is onboard and its a Matrox G200
The second adapter is an Ati firPpro V3900.

The video subsystem does not seem to recognize the second monitor as a display.

Both adapters are seen by the system and have a driver attached.

```
sudo lshw -c display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Turks GL [FirePro V3900]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=radeon latency=0 mode=2560x1440 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1440
       resources: iomemory:3ff0-3fef irq:53 memory:3fff0000000-3ffffffffff memory:d9fc0000-d9fdffff ioport:ec00(size=256) memory:d9000000-d901ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G200eR2
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=mgag200 latency=64 maxlatency=32 mingnt=16
       resources: irq:19 memory:d4000000-d4ffffff memory:dbffc000-dbffffff memory:db000000-db7fffff memory:c0000-dffff

no@r720:~$ lspci | grep 'VGA'
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks GL [FirePro V3900]
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2
```

and both are available to xserver

```
no@r720:~$ xrandr   --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x7f cap: 0x0 crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x47 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 6 outputs: 2 associated providers: 0 name:TURKS @ pci:0000:04:00.0
himi@r720:~$
```

However I am unable to get any display on the secondary adapter and the desktop display configurations only show the display attached to the matrox adapter.

I tried the Gnome desktop with gtm3 and I also tried installing KDE Plasma and switching the desktop manager to SDDM and same issue, only one display available for configuration through the desktop control panel.

On a side note I also tried an older Nvidia quadro p400 card and got the same symptoms. When I tried to use Nvidias proprietary drivers the system gets stuck about halfway into booting trying to start something over and over ( screen flashes this too fast to see ).

I downloaded the proprietary Ati driver but the installer would error out saying the x subsystem was an unsupported version ( too new ) and rolling back the xwindow subsytem for these older cards did not seem wise.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks!

Update

Update I saw some similar issues where installing and \ or re-configuring the display manager worked. I tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm. No luck. Then I tried installing lightdm and rebooting. also no luck. My /var/log/gpu-manager.log file does not show much either.

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? no
Is radeon loaded? yes
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 1002:674a
BusID "PCI:4@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Vendor/Device Id: 102b:534
BusID "PCI:12@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "radeon"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "mgag200"
Found "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "radeon"
output 0:
    card1-DVI-I-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card1: 1
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "radeon"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "mgag200"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "radeon"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "mgag200"
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 2
Has amd? yes
Has intel? no
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 2
Has the system changed? No
Unsupported discrete card vendor: 1002
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Update I saw some similar issues where installing and \ or re-configuring the display manager worked. I tried sudo

Comment: I _think_ you need to setup multiseat. Cannot help further right now